Specialized UserList and Static Type Checking
I'm specializing UserList as below.  The problem is that with Python 3.11, in PyCharm 2024.2.4 (Pro), I get a type warning on the line c:IntItems = a + b.  The warning says:  Expected type 'IntItems', got 'UserList[int]' instead.  I would expect + to return a thing of type IntItems.
from __future__ import annotations

from collections import UserList

class IntItems(UserList[int]):
    def __init__(self, values):
        if values is None:
            values = []
        super().__init__(values)

a = IntItems([1, 2, 3])
b = IntItems([4, 5, 6])
c:IntItems = a + b

If I override the __add__() method by calling super(), that doesn't solve the problem.  The warning goes away on the line c:IntItems = a + b, but reappears on the line return super().__add__(other).
    def __add__(self, other: IntItems) -> IntItems:
        return super().__add__(other)

If I override the __add__() method by duplicating UserList.__add__() with a small modification and some additional static typing, it works. (The static type checking in the def line doesn't look necessary, but it clarifies things for humans.)  That seems like overkill just to get static typing not to throw a warning.
    def __add__(self, other:IntItems) -> IntItems:
        if isinstance(other, IntItems):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other.data)
        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other)
        return self.__class__(self.data + list(other))

Is there a better way for me to solve this problem?  Does the static type checker need to be fixed?  Could UserList.__add__() be modified to make this work without an override?
I found that if I change the line to c:IntItems = IntItems(a + b) the warning goes away. But, again, this seems like it should be unnecessary. It 'ought' to work as originally written.

PyCharm is at fault here; c should indeed have been of type IntItems. Quick fix: c = typing.cast(IntItems, a + b). I'll see if I can find a bug report on YouTrack.
